Question about error raw query string using gorm
I generate raw query like that
UPDATE 
  public.openedu_user_tokens AS t 
SET 
  update_at = c.update_at, 
  delete_at = c.delete_at, 
  user_id = c.user_id, 
  org_id = c.org_id, 
  email = c.email, 
  token = c.token, 
  event = c.event, 
  expiry_time = c.expiry_time, 
  send_email = c.send_ email, 
  verify_date = c.verify_date, 
  redirect_url = c.redirect_url 
FROM 
  (
    VALUES 
      (
        $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$, 
        $9$, $10$, $11$, $12$
      ), 
      (
        $13$, $14$, $15$, $16$, $17$, $18$, $19$, 
        $20$, $21$, $22$, $23$, $24$
      )
  ) AS c(
    id, update_at, delete_at, user_id, 
    org_id, email, token, event, expiry_time, 
    send_email, verify_date, redirect_url
  ) 
WHERE 
  t.id = c.id;

I very make sure that the value pass into placeholder is correct but then I got an error. I think maybe gorm raise error when see that line update_at = c.update_at instead of update_at = ?.

"update_at" is of type bigint but expression is of type text (SQLSTATE 42804)


Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

You can just set the values into struct and pass the struct to Gorm Updates method.
https://gorm.io/docs/update.html
if you want to use Exec method you should use ? instead of $1 ... and pass the parameters like this
db.Exec(`
    UPDATE public.openedu_user_tokens AS t 
    SET 
      update_at = ?, 
      delete_at = ?, 
      user_id = ?, 
      org_id = ?, 
      email = ?, 
    ...
    WHERE 
      t.id = c.id`,updatedAt,deletedAt,userId,orgId,email,...)

I prefer to pass the struct instead of pass parameters one by one

It appears your answer has syntactical problems.
